# $q$-derivative satisfying linear approximation characterization

Tags: derivatives, asymptotics, q-analogs

Suppose instead of defining the derivative as
$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$$
we define it as
$$f_q'(x) = \lim_{q\to 1}\frac{f(qx) - f(x)}{qx - x}.$$

Does this alternative definition still satisfy the linear approximation characterization of the derivative, i.e. do we have
$$f(x + h) = f(x) + f_q'(x)h + o(h)$$
as we do with $f'(x)$?

I understand some care must be taken at $x = 0$.

Comment: By L'Hopital, isn't the limit, when $x\neq 0.$ equal to $f'(x)?$ At least when $f'$ is continuous at $x.$ I guess it is possible for $f_q'$ to exist when $f'$ doesn't exist, for aberrant $f?$